# How to remove react-native-elements in react-native project

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to remove react-native-elements in my react-native project.

`yarn remove react-native-elements
yarn remove react-native-vector-icons`

when I remove this module and its dependence, I got an error .

`` error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-elements` from `/Users/assetfun/Desktop/amigo/src/components/registerLogin/registerLogin.js`: Module `react-native-elements` does not exist in the Haste module map ``

[image]
this method can't solve the problem.

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

want someone help

Comment: Have you made sure that `react-native-elements` and `react-native-vector-icons` are not imported and used in any file?.  Looks like `registerLogin.js` has reference to these modules.`yarn remove <package>` will only update package.json and yarn.lock file, not your source files. Check your source files.

Comment: thanks ~ , I just make a simple mistake 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you don't import react-native-elements and react-native-vector-icons in any file (surely you import it in registerLogin.js).

Answer (score 1):

Even you removed that you try to import that module in your registerLogin.js . So please remove that and try again.